# How to perform memset of a pointer variable of a struct which is a pointer var of another struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memset

I have 2 `struct`s:

```
struct A
{    
  B *b;
}a;

struct B
{
  int* Info;
} b;
```

How do I perform `memset` of info in C?

```
memset((a->b->Info,0,sizeof(int));
```

Info has to be `memset` with 0. This has to be done for 34 values. Can that be done through for loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: Confusing when you name your variables A and B and then say, "How do I perform `memset` of info in C?"

Comment: Why call `memset` on an an uninitialized pointer, unless you initialized it somewhere else (in which case, best explicitly mention this in your question). If you `malloc` the int somewhere, why not use `calloc`, it'll automatically initialize the memory to 0

Answer (score 1):

When you define a struct, you're actually creating a user defined data type. In your code above, A is the datatype, a is the variable of that type. Same goes for B and b.

`a.b -> Info` is how you should access Info via A, in your case. `.` operator is used to access members of a stuct using a normal struct variable (non-pointer). If you defined a pointer `x` of type A,  *then* you should use `x->b->Info`.

You can learn about C structures from here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

Comment: It helps to remember that `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`

Comment: the mistake i had done is  malloc was missed .Hence that piece of code crashed when a null pointer was accessed.Thanks for the inputs!!.

Answer (score 1):

Define `a` and `b` in the right order and initialise them:

```
struct B
{
  int * Info;
} b = {
    NULL;
  };

struct A
{    
  B * b;
} a = {   
    &b
  };
```

Now `a.b->info` is `NULL`.